# Java JComboBox selection checked but the combobox doesn't show the selected item

Tags: java, macos, jcombobox

I have a situation that I want some advice on. The listeners of a JComboBox all work as I'd expect.

The JComboBox is created using the constructor that takes an array as argument. The argument is an ArrayList which is converted using the toArray method. The JComboBox is setEditable(false) and setEnabled(false). I'm not sure what else to tell you. JDK 1.8, Mac OS X 10.9.5 and (mis)using NetBeans 8.0.2

What is wrong is that although the underlying values and computations happen when you select, say "-4", i.e. all listeners get the value correctly, the GUI does not display "-4" but rather, it displays the previous selection.

This does not happen every time. When it does happen, if I (change the focus?) Cmd-Tab (on a Mac) away or click on another window (any window) and come back, the value displays correctly.

If I click on the drop-down and see the list, the check mark is definitely on the selected item, not the one currently displayed. And when I let go (without selecting) the screen is corrected.

I've done some things to try to get it to update, most are grasping at straws (ItemListener that sets the selected item to the one it just got; repaint() here and there...).

This is annoying to the users. They doubt they have selected, so they select twice. Or they select and move. All logs and debug show the selected item is the one they intended.

One of these JComboBox (dropdowns) has a button beside it, that takes the name selected and loads a set of values from a setup file. One can watch the displayed (and not selected) name change to the selected name when the button is pressed.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: post a minimal, runnable example showing your problem

Comment: I'll try. It is difficult (for me) because I wonder if a ton of other things could be involved. I wish I could just point you guys at the whole code-base... but...